# automotive_app_desc not found error Android Auto development

Tags: android, maui, auto, android-auto

I am using .NET MAUI on Visual Studio. I added the proper meta-data to AndroidManifest.xml and created "automotive_app_desc". Despite everything being done correctly, when I rebuild my solution, I get these errors:
"resource xml/automotive_app_desc not found"
and
"failed processing manifest"

I have swapped around file locations, renamed things, restarted the entire project a few times, and have googled for DAYS. I have only found resources telling me to do exactly what I have already done. I have found no solution.

## ** these are the contents of AndroidManifest.xml **

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      package="com.austin.youtubecontrol" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="test">
        <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"     android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="YouTube Control">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application" 
                       android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />
            <meta-data android:name="androidx.car.app.minCarApiLevel"
                       android:value="1" />
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
    </manifest>
```

## ** and automotive_app_desc.xml **

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <automotiveAPP>
        <uses name="media" />
    </automotiveAPP>
```

Comment: You can check this link about [how to extend your media app to Android for Cars](https://developer.android.com/media/implement/surfaces/cars).

Comment: Well obviously I have already done that, or I wouldn't be asking this question. Did you look at the link you just sent me?